# Define a color in a tikz style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How do I do a `definecolor` in a `/.style`?

```
\pgfkeys{/IMMstyle/.style={
         inputnode/.style={shape=ellipse,draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=5.0mm},
         \definecolor{dpred}{rgb}{0.50,0.35,0}
        }}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Does this post help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/how-to-define-a-random-number-with-xcolor-and-tikz-pgf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a `/.code` (or `/.code 2 args`, or `/.code n args`) key that executes your desired code. To define a new color within a style, you could define a key

```
\tikzset{
    define color/.code 2 args={
        \definecolor{#1}{rgb}{#2}
    }
}
```

Your example could look like  this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    define color/.code 2 args={
        \definecolor{#1}{rgb}{#2}
    },
    /IMMstyle/.style={
         inputnode/.style={
            shape=ellipse,
            draw,
            inner sep=2pt,
            minimum size=5mm
         },
         define color={dpred}{0.80,0.35,0}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [/IMMstyle,inputnode,fill=dpred] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

For future reference, I would guess that most Googlers will arrive here trying to define a style which *contains* a defined colour (rather than defining the colour within the style itself).

That's easy to do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{dkblue}{rgb} {0.00,0.33,0.68}
\tikzset{
    myStyle/.style = {draw=dkblue, very thick, rectangle}
}

\node [myStyle] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
```