# list of numbers as command option, numbers will be used to define colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, color, pgfkeys

What I'm trying to do is to pass a list of numbers as an option to a command. The numbers will be used later to define colors inside a `tikz` picture. The first part I can do, here's an example

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% keys
\pgfkeys{
 /namespace/.is family,
 /namespace,
 color fractions/.store in = \colorfractions,
}

% command
\newcommand\colorcommand[1][]{%
 \pgfkeys{/namespace, #1}%
 %
 \begin{tikzpicture}[]
   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/pgf-tikz-how-to-store-strings-in-array
   \node[draw] at (0, 0){\pgfmathparse{\colorfractions[1]}\pgfmathresult};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\colorcommand[%
  color fractions = {{{0.1,0.2,0.3}}},
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second part is the one that's giving me problems. For example, I can use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/how-to-define-a-random-number-with-xcolor-and-tikz-pgf) answer to define a color,

```
(...)
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/how-to-define-a-random-number-with-xcolor-and-tikz-pgf
   \xdefinecolor{localcolor}{rgb}{\pgfmathparse{\colorfractions[1]}\pgfmathresult, 1.0, 1.0}

   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/pgf-tikz-how-to-store-strings-in-array
   \node[draw, fill = localcolor] at (0, 0){\pgfmathparse{\colorfractions[1]}\pgfmathresult};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
(...)
```

But it fails! Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expand the color like this but the following works:

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% keys
\pgfkeys{
 /namespace/.is family,
 /namespace,
 color fractions/.store in = \colorfractions,
}

% command
\newcommand\colorcommand[1][]{%
 \pgfkeys{/namespace, #1}%
 %
 \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myfraction}{\colorfractions[1]}
    \xdefinecolor{localcolor}{rgb}{\myfraction, 1.0, 1.0}
   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/pgf-tikz-how-to-store-strings-in-array
   \node[draw,fill=localcolor] at (0, 0){\pgfmathparse{\colorfractions[1]}\pgfmathresult};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\colorcommand[%
  color fractions = {{{0.1,0.2,0.3}}},
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It also works with `\definecolor{localcolor}{rgb}{\myfraction, 1.0, 1.0}` instead of `\xdefinecolor` and so does

```
\pgfmathparse{\colorfractions[1]}
\definecolor{localcolor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult, 1.0, 1.0}
```

or

```
\pgfmathparse{\colorfractions[1]}
\xdefinecolor{localcolor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult, 1.0, 1.0}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm